# Crontab doesn't work - EC2 - Amazon Web Service (aws) - Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I don't know why, but my crontab won't work in the Ubunut 14.0.x - Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2.

I've already tried a lot of things.

e.g.

```
sudo nano test.cron

--> * * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py
```

i've also tried

```
--> * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py
```

and then

```
chrontab test.cron
```

---

```
crontab -l
```

will give me the next result :

```
MAILTO=myemail@hotmail.com
* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py
```

or

```
MAILTO=myemail@hotmail.com
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py
```

but crontab doesn't do anything :(

even-though, the python script works perfectly if i execute the script normally...

```
import sys, urllib
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re, os
import urllib.parse
from time import localtime, gmtime, strftime, mktime, sleep

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import csv
from geopy.geocoders.googlev3 import GoogleV3
from _ast import Try
import datetime

def main(args):

    keys = ['Name', 'Latitude','Longitude','Altitude','firstDay']     
    f = open("testNUUUUU.csv", 'w')
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow( keys )
    finally:
        f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        main(sys.argv[1:]) # chop off the sys.argv[0] (script name) and pass the rest.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nUser Break.')
```

Also, i'm pretty sure that the crontab server is running :

```
sudo service cron restart
cron stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 3210
```

- I've also tried

  crontab -e

without any result :'(

---

Thus, if I execute the code into the terminal --> it works (it will create the file)

If I want to let crontab execute the code,  it won't work :'(

With other words,  can someone help?

Comment: did you grant sudo rights to that user for python? did you try running the script manually under the same userid that cron would be? try running it as root? just because it works fine for you in your shell under your userid doesn't mean it will under another user's id/shell.

Comment: @MarcB - an humble question,  how do you do that

Comment: file: /etc/sudoers

Comment: Have you checked the logs? They may be at /var/log/syslog.

Comment: @arjabbar - the log says - 
Jul  8 17:56:01 ip-172-31-20-19 CRON[5418]: (ubuntu) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py)
Jul  8 17:56:01 ip-172-31-20-19 CRON[5419]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/test.py)

Comment: Post the answer as an answer so people can find it. Don't edit the answer into the question, and don't add "solved" to the title. (Yes, it's perfectly ok to answer your own question and to accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Solution**
 : Apparently, the whole setup was correct, right from the start. The only thing which I didn't notice was, that crontab will be executed in the ***home/____/*** directory. Because of the fact that my original python script required some other files (files which he couldn't find because of the *wrong* directory.), it couldn't execute it properly + with the test-script, I didn't noticed that the outcome was written in the home/___/ directory....

thus...

**Solution**

clean / remove all the crontabs (optional, i guess)

```
crontab -r
```

create an crontab-task file

```
sudo nano myCrontabTask.cron
```

edit the crontab-task file

```
#
# 1 * * * * <-- crontab task, which will be executed every hour
# cd /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/ <-- directory where everything should happen
# sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/scriptGetMeteoData.py <-- execute the python script
#
1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/ && sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/scriptGetMeteoData.py
```

add the crontab-task to crontab

```
crontab myCrontabTask.cron
```

Check if the crontabTask is added

```
crontab -l
```

And if you did everything correctly, you'll see your crontab task

- Via this solution, it will be executed on **user-level** - If you want to have en crontab-task on **root-level** you should use

  crontab -e

without creating a *.cron* file

Answer (score 1):

My top gotcha: If you forget to add a newline at the end of the crontab file. In other words, the crontab file should end with an empty line.

Below is the relevant section in the man pages for this issue (man crontab then skip to the end):

> cron requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline character.
>   If the last entry in a crontab is missing the newline, cron will consider the crontab (at least partially) broken and refuse to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in a file `test.py` starting with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

then give execute permission to that script using

```
chmod a+x test.py
```

and use the full path of your `test.py` file in your `crontab`.

See documentation of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which is handling the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: still no result :s

Comment: do you know what the  execution path is, from crontab? - i added  -  os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData") to my python file -.-" and it worked ....  thus i suspect, that i worked the whole time  but my files are  somewhere .....  where crontab  get executed ....

Comment: Did you check your home directory?

Comment: Now I did :) 
i've changed the crontab line into : 1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/ && sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/MeteoData/scriptGetMeteoData.py