# Unable to get python script working through crontab on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to execute a python file at a particular time hosted on an EC2 instance in AWS using crontab and it is not working.

I have the following line which execute `report.py` at 1.30pm every day:

```
 30 13 *  *  * /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/nginx/report/report.py
```

The script runs perfectly fine when executed from the command line and I've made sure the crond service is also. started. But for some reason the script in not be triggered by the service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crontab doesn't work - EC2 - Amazon Web Service (aws) - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269584/crontab-doesnt-work-ec2-amazon-web-service-aws-ubuntu)